# I can't add Wireless Adaptor in External Virtual Switch Network in Hyper-V. Error: Object Not Found

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I was tried to create a virtual switch network in Hyper-V. I was select **External** and then select **Create Virtual Switch**. ([Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RbcP.jpg))

Under **Connection Type** I selected External Network, Then I select **Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adaptor**. ([Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiTJs.jpg))

After that When I tried to click on **Apply** button, but an error occurred that **Object Not Found** ([Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuiWF.jpg))

After this error my internet connection get lost. If I again try to connect to my Wi-Fi, I get connected to my Wi-Fi, but it shows that **No Internet**, even could not connect to any Wi-Fi. ([Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gralv.jpg))

Now if I disable the Hyper-V from **Turn Windows features on or off** and restart my Laptop, again I can connect to the Wi-Fi.

Now if I try to again create a virtual switch, the same problem occurred and again I have to disable Hyper-V for use internet.

Comment: WiFi cannot be bridged to Ethernet.

Comment: @DanielB Then how can I use Wi-Fi for access internet in my VM? I can use WiFi in VMWare or Oracle VM Box, but why not in Hyper-V ?

Comment: Hyper-V on Windows 10 1709+ comes with “Default Switch”, a preconfigured Virtual Switch that uses NAT networking. Maybe that’s good enough for you?

Comment: Wi-Fi _can_ be bridged to Ethernet (the spec says so, and millions of Wi-Fi access points routinely do that) -- but Wi-Fi _clients_ cannot act as bridges at all, no matter what they're trying to bridge to, unless they implement L2 NAT like VirtualBox does (magically rewriting the MAC addresses). I don't know if that's the reason Hyper-V doesn't allow you to use a Wi-Fi client interface for bridging, but it's very likely.

Comment: From what I can see in my own Hyper-V, it does not natively support USB Passthrough. It can be done, so you may wish to try a USB wireless card.   https://www.nakivo.com/blog/performing-hyper-v-usb-passthrough/

Answer (score 6):

There is a weird bug which happens with some WiFi cards where the Network Bridge is not created (this is the missing "object"). All credit goes to the comments posted by Craig in here: https://pomeroy.me/2020/08/hyper-v-virtual-switch-creation-woes/

Craig S. In this link discovered why this happens: the Network Bridge disappears from network adapters. Disabling and enabling the WiFi adapter while applying the external virtual switch change will magically bring the Network Bridge back and the virtual switch setup will succeed immediately!

Restarting the host and VM usually is a good idea after that.

Comment: That link actually solve my problem. You should consider update your answer with the solution in the link, just in case it is unavailable in the future.